# How to Design a Crystal Report at runtime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

How can i Design a Crystal Report at runtime which i already create, like dragging in dataset values and move it around, at the form design it self when the form is running. Thank you

Comment: The best you can do is create some Reports and allow a user to select them at run time. Designing User specific is possible but with a lot of formula for dimensions, x values etc...which will be complicated

Comment: I'm not aware of a Business Intelligence or reporting tool like Crystal Reports that can achieve what you want to do.  This might be a good question to ask in the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) community of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well, you cannot design at runtime according to what I know but you can give a try to dynamic columns. It may help you.